# Should Photo Critiques be allowed?

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion, critiques

Should photo-stack allow posts asking for photo critiquing? Perhaps limit to X number of images, and make the page community wiki.

Comment: See also [Can we re-open the door to something a little like photo critique?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique) and [How can we do photo critiques?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/815/how-can-we-do-photo-critiques)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Photo critique was voted to be [off topic during the definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing/2172#2172) of the site, so I would say it should be regarded as such.

---

**Update:**
Suggestion of FAQ text:

**Question:** *Can I post a photo for critique?*

**Answer:** (SiteName) is not a site for photo critique. However, if you have an image that turned out in a way that you did not expect, or where you want to achieve a specific result, questions about this are on-topic. Examples of such questions include:

- *"I have this landscape image and the ground is too dark and the sky is too bright. What can I do to fix that?"*
- *"What can I do to isolate the subject from the background better in scenarios like in this image?"*.

Comment: Probably there's a FAQ answer to be written here to define exactly what *critique* means, as the form I suggested could be interpreted as a critique but is getting a fair amount of upvotes.

Comment: ...and during the definition phase, it was considered that questions like "why is this so horribly overexposed in this corner yet underexposed to the left" would be acceptable (per Fredrik's link). That's not inconsistent with what you'd suggested.

Comment: @Reid and @Rowland: I have update the answer with a suggested FAQ text on the matter. I guess there should be specific faq posts created by I am a bit unsure about the process.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: At present we're generally tagging questions that discuss FAQ matters with `[faq-suggestion]`, as explained here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11/site-attribute-questions-top-7

Comment: I like it. I took the liberty of editing; feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: Just to test it out/be the devil's advocate, where would this FAQ text put questions like: "I tried to emulate X by doing Y, do you think I was successful?" vs "I tried to emulate X by doing Y, why do you think it didn't work?"

Answer (score 9):

I'm skeptical about general critiques, but I think that questions of the form *I want to achieve X, I've tried A, B, and C and this is what I got* are certainly on-topic.