# Is it OK to post photos to gather comments and reviews?

Tags: discussion, faq, asking-questions

Basically I'm a newbie picture-taker and want feedback on what I've done. Does the photo.SE philosophy forbid posting photos to gather feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [discussed a while back](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed), and the general consensus was that you could post a picture to illustrate a specific question about it (For example, if you were asking how to take a product shot and make the background transparent, without losing the shadows); But this isn't the place to post your pictures with vague or subjective question like "Is this composed correctly?" or "what do you think of this?".

The is a general [chat room associated to the site](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211/photo-se), which has seen people swapping links to their Flickr profiles (etc.) and swapping opinions on pictures.