# Idea: Photo of the Week Activity - Editing

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What do people think of occasionally having a untouched up photo posted and then having anyone who wants to do whatever touch up they desire.  Anyone who wants to participate could submit their touch up and alterations at the end of some set period and we could vote and discuss what people did.

I figure it might make an interesting way to learn about different styles and how members of the community see the same image differently.  Does it sound like an idea people are interested in?

Comment: Are you thinking of this as something for the main site, or for here on meta? Or for the blog?

Comment: I have the same question. How would we manage this? If we were a normal forum, I think we could make it work well. We might be able to do it on meta, but it won't be particularly visible that way. I think it is very useful, and I've seen this done on other forums quite successfully. I think we just need to think about how it would be managed before we do.

Comment: @Mattdm - unsure, throwing it out here as an idea, details I'm open to discussion.  I would expect it would probably be something either on meta or the blog though.  It doesn't really fit the main site I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic Stack Exchange engine would work fairly well for this; user posts a raw image (either literally RAW or an out-ofcamera jpeg) as the question, and the answers are likewise visual. Answers might be subjective, but the questioner could still pick a favorite as the accepted answer.

It would be nice if we could make sub-sites. We *could* try just allowing this on the main site (with a tag like [postprocess-this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postprocess-this)), but I'm not sure it's ideal to mix reputation and voting with strict Q&A voting. (This is similarly the case with photo critique questions.)

Maybe it's worth it, though: I think this activity would help build up a more active artistic community.

Comment: Doing it on meta would get around the rep worries, but of course limits exposure...

Answer (score 1):

I love doing these - I don't know if we have enough consistent participation to make it work or not, would have to try it and see.  But this reminds me of discussions about photo critiques, and based on those discussions I would think it would have to be on meta.

[Should Photo Critiques be allowed?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed)

[Can we re-open the door to something a little like photo critique?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this would be a fascinating way to see different styles and to be able to compare notes and learn from each other as well as being an interesting showcase of the skills within the community.