# Why are people calling this composition question "primarily opinion based"?

Tags: discussion

A few people have voted to close [When does "Fill the frame" become "Too tightly framed"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62101/when-does-fill-the-frame-become-too-tightly-framed) as primary opinion based. I strongly disagree! Whether a certain composition is good or bad is certainly opinion-based, but the actual terms and concepts have real meaning and can be usefully talked about. Remember, this is *Photography* Stack Exchange, not *Objective Technical Questions About Cameras* Stack Exchange.

Is there something in particular about the wording that makes you reach for the close button here? The asker uses the terms "good" and "bad", but clearly in reference to advice received, not asking to know whether the composition itself is good or bad.

This is not an [open-ended photo critique request](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed). It might be construed as a request for improving [an aspect of the photographs](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2042/1943) — but that's [on topic](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But I don't think it's even that; it's a question about what those terms mean and how they are applied — and while that's not a *math problem*, I really don't understand how that's even *mostly* opinion-based, let alone *primarily*.

Comment: I was wondering about that, I see nothing wrong with the question (and may reopen it if it does close).

Comment: My hunch is that "primarily opinion-based" may not be quite the right language for a reason to close, in the context of a place where there are acceptable questions related to aesthetics. Maybe the wording itself sends the wrong message?

Comment: Another thought is that, while that question is well constructed and answerable, it does bear some *superficial* resemblance to a common form of the other kind, and if people are behaving as sloppy heuristic algorithms rather than actually taking the time to consider the question, they'll go all false-positive based on that.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ – this is "good subjective".